# Redirigir a usuario a la ruta de la URL desde un Email con Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Tengo una tienda en línea, una vez que el usuario crea una orden se le envía un e-mail notificándole de dicha orden y además tiene un botón que lo lleva al la web donde se encuentra su orden (Para verla cuando lo desee), en intentado con lo siguiente y no lo logro (en versiones anteriores me funcionaba).

El botón

```
<a href="{{url('/login?redirect_to=home/orders/'.$order->id)}}" class="button">Ver orden</a>
```

También siguiendo los pasos que hacía con las versiones anteriores de Laravel agregué al Controllador `LoginController` lo siguiente

```
public function showLoginForm(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('redirect_to')) {
        session()->put('redirect_to', $request->input('redirect_to'));
    }

    return view('auth.login');
}

public function redirectTo()
{
    if (session()->has('redirect_to'))
        return session()->pull('redirect_to');

    return $this->redirectTo;
}
```

También de esta manera

```
public function showLoginForm(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('redirect_to')) {
        $url = request()->fullUrl();
        if (false !== strpos($url,'&url=')) {
            session()->put('redirect_to', $request->input('redirect_to').'&url='.request()->get('url'));
        }
        else {
            session()->put('redirect_to', $request->input('redirect_to'));
        }
    }

    return view('admin.auth.login');
}

public function redirectTo()
{
    if (session()->has('redirect_to'))
        return session()->pull('redirect_to');

    return $this->redirectTo;
}
```

Pero no funciona, el usuario al dar clic en el botón que se encuentra en el correo electrónico siempre es llevado al `home` del sitio, esté o no logeado.

Actualización (Rutas)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se que version estabas usando antes, pero hace tiempo que existe [redirect()->intended('/')](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users) > The intended method provided by Laravel's redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. Si haces la authentication como en el ejemplo de la documentation, ya no necesitas toda esa logica manual,  en el boton del mail pones la url de la orden, y laravel se encarga de redirigir si el usuario no estaba loguedo

Comment: Gracias, aún no me queda claro como hacerlo, yo uso Laravel Auth, debo sobre escribir un método en el controlador? hice pruebas que se me ocurrieron pero no lo logré.

Comment: Si el problema es que el usuario no es redirigido a la url a la que se dirigia despues de autenticarse, muestranos la ruta y la funcion que atienden la peticion POST del login. Puedes ver esa informacion con el comando `php artisan route:list`

Comment: No, cuando un usuario se autentica en la Web lo lleva a la ruta `home` correctamente, el problema está cuando hace clic en el botón del correo electrónico que lo lleva a la web con la siguiente ruta `{{url('/login?redirect_to=home/orders/'.$order->id)}}`, ya que una vez que se autentica cuando llega a través de ese enlace lo lleva igualmente a la ruta `home` en vez de la ruta `home/orders/'.$order->id`, si hace clic en el botón del e-mail estando ya autenticado si lo lleva a la ruta correspondiente.

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta con las rutas, yo uso Laravel Auth

Comment: Disculpa, si funciona, el problema estaba en un componente Livewire que tengo. Muchas gracias!